# C# under Linux, Process.Start() exception of "No such file or directory"

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process

I am having trouble calling a program with the Process class to start a program. The hierarchy to the executable is in under the bin directory while the current working directory needs to be under the lib directory.

```
/project
    /bin
        a.out (this is what I need to call)
    /lib
        (this is where I need to be in order for a.out to work)
```

I have set the `WorkingDirectory = "path/lib"` and the `"FileName = "../bin/a.out"`. However I am getting an error of:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory
```

I tried setting `WorkingDirectory` to absolute and relative path, but neither works. I have written a bash script to executes a.out from the lib directory, and using the Process class I call the bash script, this works but I want to do this without the bash script workaround. So how do I resolve this pathing issue?

Comment: What is the working directory of the parent process when you call `Process.Start`?

Comment: Have you considered using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` to construct the path?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer @mjwills, the parent process starts in `/home/cli2/tmp/test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1` while the program that I want to get called is in `/home/cli2/tmp/program/lib`. Using the `Path.GetDirectoryName(...)` gives me the parent process path.

Comment: Just to add, I set `FileName = ls` with `WorkingDirectory = home/cli2/tmp/program/lib`, and I do see the program that I want to call, but when I change FileName to that program, it gives me the no such file or directory error. As well as `File.Exists("/home/cli2/tmp/program/lib/a.out")` returns true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered your [other very similar question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613775/c-sharp-under-linux-workingdirectory-not-working-properly/52880852#52880852), but here is a specific answer to this one.

Forget about WorkingDirectory, it does not specify the location of the new process executable unless you set `UseShellExecute = true`. [Here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-2.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory).

You have to use a relative path to the project root in FileName. Like this: `process.StartInfo.FileName="bin/wrapper.sh";`

I don't know of a way to execute a file and set that process' working directory on Linux from within dotnet core and C#.

What you could do is create a wrapper script to execute your file in lib.

Under our project root we have two files. Be sure both have `chmod +x`.

- `bin/wrapper.sh` - this file will execute lib/a.out
- `lib/a.out` - Hello, World!

#### bin/wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd lib
pwd
./a.out
```

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SO_Question_52599105
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName="bin/wrapper.sh";
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

#### === OUTPUT ===

```
larntz@dido:/home/larntz/SO_Question_52599105$ ls
bin  hello.c  lib  obj  Program.cs  SO_Question_52613775.csproj

larntz@dido:/home/larntz/SO_Question_52599105$ ls bin/
Debug  wrapper.sh

larntz@dido:/home/larntz/SO_Question_52599105$ ls lib/
a.out

larntz@dido:/home/larntz/SO_Question_52599105$ dotnet run
/home/larntz/SO_Question_52599105/lib
Hello, World!
```