# C# under Linux, WorkingDirectory not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process, path

I have an issues with `WorkingDirectory`, and it is not setting the desired path correctly. I wrote a simple hello world test program, `a.out`, to try out `WorkingDirectory`. And the directory hierarchy is such:

```
/home/cli2/test
   /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/subdir/
      a.out
   /obj
   Program.cs
   test.csproj
```

I have the following settings for the Process class

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "a.out"
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/subdir/";
```

When I execute `dotnet run`, I would get an error of:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory
```

The issue that confuses me is that if I move `a.out` to the top directory such that:

```
/home/cli2/project
   /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/subdir/
   /obj
   Program.cs
   test.csproj
   a.out
```

While having the same `StartInfo` settings, `process.start()` executes the hello world program without error. Furthermore, if I change `FileName = "ls"` with the original subdirectory hierarchy, it does print out `a.out`. For that case the `WorkingDirectory` is behaving as expected. So I do understand this discrepancy and why I cannot call `a.out` in a different directory.

Also I have tried both absolute and relative path for `WorkingDirectory`, neither works when I call `a.out`.

Comment: Hi, you can try to make a few checks if the file is existing it will not throw an exception by **File.Exists** and also you have type when you are trying to specify your directory more correctly way to point at your suborder is **"\\subdir\\"**

Comment: @VadimNikiforov `File.Exists` returns true. I have `/subdir/` because it is running under a Linux system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` in this case is **not** the location of the executable.

That is what's causing the behavior your are experiencing, and the meaning `process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` changes based on the value of `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute`.

---

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-2.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory):

> The WorkingDirectory property behaves differently when UseShellExecute is true than when UseShellExecute is false.
>
> When UseShellExecute is false, the WorkingDirectory property is not used to find the executable. Instead, its value applies to the process that is started and only has meaning within the context of the new process.

---

The default value for `UseShellExecute` in dotnet core is `false`. I have experienced strange things when setting `UseShellExecute` to true on Linux.

Personally, I would keep it false and make sure to use the full path or a path relative to the project root directory like this:

`process.StartInfo.FileName="bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/subdir/a.out";`